# I need to make a function that colors the background of an input text

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation

I need to make a function that colors the background of an input. That's it.
I will call that function later. I am using it for a form validation.

```
function makeRed(input) {  
        input.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
```

The **problem is that when i hit submit the red color just blinks**. It doesn't stay red.
When i call the function i do it like this:

```
function samepass() {
        var a = document.getElementById("pass1").value; //pass1 is the id of the input in HTML
        var b = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
        if (a != b){
            makeRed(pass1);
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form action="tema.html" method="post" onSubmit="return samepass()">                    

                    <label for="pass1" class="lbl">Password: </label>
                    <input type="password" id="pass1" name="pass1" class="inp"/><br /><br />


                </form>
```

Comment: make sure to `return false` and `pass1` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function makeRed(input) {  
        document.getElementById("input").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
```